# Welcome to emergency mode error

Tags: boot

I have LinuxMint 18 KDE as my main OS. I wanted to try Zorin OS 12 on another partition, like I had many times before. And so I did, but, when I tried to get to LM, I get welcomed by the emergency mode. I have opened the `journalctl -xb` as it told me and I got a snapshot of the problem:

[image: Open in new tab]

I can not provide a text log because it is gone after restart and I can not enter in the main OS by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>. I think it is because the two partitions are next to each other (/dev/sda6 is LM and /dev/sda7 is Zorin) and although i did not change the size of the partition, I think the installer musthave messed that up.

L.E. 
error in text

Also the error in text:

```
systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-b7e7e9fc\x2d17a2\x2d4308\x2daf2f\x2de941f3c86400.device: job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-b7e7e9fc\x2d17a2\x2d4308\x2daf2f\ ...device.start failed
Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-b7e7e9fc\x2d17a2\x2d4308\x2daf2f\x2de941f3c86400.device
Subject: Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-b7e7e9fc\x2d17a2\x2d4308\x2daf2f\x2de941f3c86400.device has failed
Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-b7e7e9fc\x2d17a2\x2d4308\x2daf2f\x2de941f3c86400.device has failed
```

The result is timeout

Comment: Have you tried booting to a live os and checking if that UUID exists?

Comment: Total noob here, please can you tell me how to do that step by step? I am on Zorin now. Can I do it from here or I need to enter live mode?

Comment: At root run blkid

Comment: sudo blkid
[sudo] password for relar: 
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="78982D58982D15E2" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="4a2af2c2-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="AC4236254235F4A4" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="4a2af2c2-02"
/dev/sda3: UUID="2AC0D813C0D7E35D" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="4a2af2c2-03"
/dev/sda5: UUID="54637fab-077e-4797-a808-3c06f0af2e50" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="4a2af2c2-05"
/dev/sda6: UUID="31a5fade-2f57-4792-8271-919f65b6ec0a" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="4a2af2c2-06"
/dev/sda7: UUID="04c5aca3-934b-4ee0-9f8d-6920e8c83d86" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="4a2af2c2-07"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve my problem by doing the following:

- I booted into another OS (this can be done also with a LiveCD)
- I went to **/etc/fstab** (on **/dev/sda6** -> the root filesystem i wanted to boot) and saw that the UUID that didn't load (starting with [**b7e7e9fc-...**] was on the partition I had installed Zorin on and it had LM Cinnamon on it (now **/dev/sda7** but with a different uuid as seen in the comments above). As such in /etc/fstab it was market as /cinnamon
- I placed a **#** in front of the line to be ignored at boot
- LM KDE system booted normally (**/dev/sda6**)